# How to invoke a p:commandButton by JavaScript on enter keypress?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have write a  and a  in my page.
When enter key was pressed ,I want to do any js check, if success post an action.

Javascript：

```
function text_onkeypress() {
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        formSubmit();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p:inputText id="context" value="#{bean.fileName}"
 onkeydown="text_onkeypress();"></p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="search" value="submit" onclick="return formSubmit();" 
 action="#{action.getResult}" ></p:commandButton>
```

when I write query("#search")[0].click() in the javascript.It can do the check, but can't do action="#{action.getResult}".

I don't know how to do the losted action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of checks do you need?

You don't need to manually submit on enter(especially when you have just one form).
If you want to submit the form only if the user enters something you could take advantage of `validateLength` tag.

```
<h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />  
        <p:inputText id="firstname"   
                value="#{personBean.firstname}"   
                required="true" requiredMessage="You have to enter your name" label="Firstname">  
            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
        </p:inputText>  
        <p:message for="firstname" />
```

See here a demo: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprAjaxStatusScript.jsf

PS:What PF version do you use?

Comment: thanks for your answer.if i want to alert() the message how to do it?

Comment: @wsxiapiaoxue You want a Javascript alert to appear when somebody types a character into the text field?  You realize that the alert box will take focus from the text box right?

Comment: @wsxiapiaoxue It isn't a good practice to show a javascript alert! That's why you can implement the primefaces `message` component, or simply use just the `required=true` and `requiredMessage="..."` without the `message` component, and your requiredMessage will still be shown, usually in the right side of the textbox

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way for you to submit your form from Javascript is to just invoke the `click()` event for the jQuery object of the `<p:commandButton>`.

Most of the Primefaces components can be accessed from Javascript by declaring the `widgetVar` attribute.  This attribute creates a Javascript variable.  Eg.

```
<p:commandButton id="search" value="submit" onclick="return formSubmit();" action="#{action.getResult}" widgetVar="searchClientVar" />
```

I can now access the variable in the `formSubmit` function.  This Javascript variable has an attribute called `jq` which references the underlying jQuery object and what you can use to invoke the click event.

```
function text_onkeypress() {
  if(event.keyCode==13) {
    searchClientVar.jq.click();
  }
}
```

This will invoke the server side `action` of the commandButton and submit the form values if they pass validation.

Comment: There is no point because the form auto-submits when the `enter` key is pressed...

Comment: @spauny I know, but I interpreted the vague question as, "How do I submit a form from Javascript with Primefaces elements?"  I was just using the KeyPress event as an example of how to do this, but this could be any done with ANY javascript event easily.